# How to generate a bespoke black and white bitmap

Tags: python, dictionary, bitmap, python-imaging-library, pixel

image example:
[image]

I want to create a black and white bitmap from scratch (not converting or manipulating an existing image) and have the ability to change individual pixels to either black or white using pixel coordinates, somehow, maybe via a dictionary?. Something like a chessboard but with one pixel per chessboard-square (if that makes sense?).I found something to generate a colour spectrum image but don't know how to adapt this.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new( 'RGB', (300,50), "black") # Create a new black image
pixels = img.load() # Create the pixel map
for i in range(img.size[0]):    # For every pixel:
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixels[i,j] = (i, j, 100) # Set the colour accordingly

img.show()
```

Zoomed in on leftmost edge of bitmap

[image]

Comment: Can you please show some exemplary output? How many single pixel values do you want to manipulate?

Comment: Hi, I have incorporated the image into the text, you may need to click on it and zoom - the pixel choice examples are at either ends of the 3 line image.

Comment: I may want to change values of a whole row/line or column from black to white, or set an individual pixel on/off.

Comment: You aren't being very clear about what you are trying to do, so it is hard to answer you in an optimal way. If your images are largely black with a few white pixels dotted here and there, you can just use indexing like you have. If you want to make many rows and columns black or white, you might be better off using Numpy, or drawing lines, or rectangles. Please give a better idea of what a finished image will look like, and where you get the data from that determines how it will look and how that data is stored/held so we can better answer.

Comment: Mark, the image in the question is precisely what I want to be able to achieve. That's a working image we use, not a simplified example. It is 1000 wide by 3 high. If you look at the leftmost end of the image you will see that column is all black, the next column is all white, and the next column has 2rows black and one row white. I will see if I can magnify it up a bit more and add a second image.

Comment: @Windy71 But how is the actual data stored? Do you have pairs of pixel coordinates and color? If you want to set a whole column, do you only have the column index, or do you have all three pixel coordinates? If you show the data, it should be possible to show a way, how to draw the image efficiently.

Comment: My apologies Hans, there is no data, at the moment these images are made manually in paint or photoshop. For the zoomed image far right column I think a dictionary where the key is the column ID and the values would be either a list of columns ( here that would be [0,1, 2])or a dict {"0": 1, "1":1, "2":0}

Comment: image data could be img_data = {"1":{"0": 1, "1":1, "2":1} , "2":{"0": 0, "1":0, "2":0} , "3":{"0": 1, "1":1, "2":0} }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do individual odd pixels here and there like this:

```
from PIL import PIL

# Create new black image - L mode for b/w
img = Image.new( 'L', (10,6))

# Make pixels at locations (0,5) and (2,1) white (255)
img.putpixel((0,5), 255)
img.putpixel((2,1), 255)

# Save result
img.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

However, if you want to do whole rows, or columns, or longer lines, I would recommend round-tripping to Numpy like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Create new black image - L mode for b/w
img = Image.new( 'L', (10,6))

# Convert to Numpy array for easy processing
na = np.array(img)

# Make row 1 white
na[1,:] = 255

# Make column 8 white
na[:,8] = 255

# Revert to PIL Image from Numpy array and save
Image.fromarray(na).save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

Or if you want to do a block:

```
... as above ...

na[1:3,5:9] = 255

... as above ...
```

[image]

Comment: Always agree on using NumPy, but only if the "input" data can be somehow used for vectorization. If there's only a long list (or dictionary) of pixels, lines, rectangles, which needs to be iterated, you could stick to [ImageDraw.line](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.line) and [ImageDraw.rectangle](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle) - if you want to avoid NumPy in your code.

Comment: @HansHirse I agree. I didn't really want to answer as the question was not very clear and I didn't want to write a 5 page tutorial to cover all possibilities... but I can't help trying to help ;-)